# Triangulator Using If Statement (Python)

Tags: python, if-statement

I worked on my code to make this program as directed...

Ask the user for three numbers that are the sides of a potential triangle.

If the sides cannot be valid sides for a triangle, tell the user “Shame on you, that is not a triangle!”, otherwise say it is valid.

If all three sides are equal, tell the user "It is an equilateral triangle".

If two of the sides are equal, tell the user "It is an isosceles triangle".

Hint: To be a triangle, the two shortest sides combined must be greater than the longest side. If the sides are A, B, and C, A + B + C must be greater than twice the longest side.

Here is what I have so far, and I think it should run perfectly but I'm getting an error when I try to run it. Anything I can do to run it smoothly? Thank you for your time.

```
 import math
a = input("Please Enter Side  A ")
b = input("Please Enter Side  B")
c = input("Please Enter Side  C ")
d = a+b+c
if d < (2*c)
     print"Shame on you, that is not a triangle!"
elif d > (2*c):
     print"You Have Two Possible Answers: "
else:
     xone = a=b=c
     xtwo = a=b
print "It's Equilateral:",xone," 
print "It's Isosceles:",xtwo,"
```

Comment: Reading what the error message says is a good start. Please have a look at your last 2 print statements.

Comment: I don't understand why they are showing up in blue for the last It. I fixed it to have the same format. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @Mephy, Can you tell me if the else statement makes sense? For Isosceles triangle, only two sides have to the same. How do I exclude c? Or is that line fine, since it's not specifying c in the line? Also after my if statement, is it alright to put print function? I don't know since my code won't run at all.

Comment: Take a closer look at the syntax, not the logic. If you're learning, you should have a guidebook, tutorial or something like that.

Comment: The reason the last `It` is showing up in cyan is because StackOverflow's code formatter sees a string that starts with the stay `"` at the end of the previous line and goes up to after `print ` (which is why `print` is red). Then there's `It`, which is outside of quotes. Then the `'` starts another string, which goes all the way up to the end of the program (because there's no matching `'`).

Answer (score 2):

Several problems that I notice:

- **Missing colon on your `if` statement.** This is the error message I get when I run it for the first time:

  ```
  if d < (2*c)
              ↑
  line 6, column 13    in tringle.py
  ```

  It's a pretty good indicator of where the problem is: the interpreter expects a colon here. So we fix that:

  ```
  if d < (2*c):
  ```

  On to the next error.
- **Dangling double quotes.** I run it for the second time, and here's the error:

  ```
  print "It's Equilateral:",xone,"
                                  ↑
  line 13, column 33   in tringle.py
  ```

  There are three sets of double quotes in this line. The first two enclose the string `It's Equilateral`, and the third starts a string which is never closed. So we get rid of that double quote (and do the same on the second print statement):

  ```
  print "It's Equilateral:", xone
  print "It's Isosceles:", xtwo
  ```
- **`xone` isn't always assigned.**. The program now runs successfully, but when I put in the three lengths 26, 13 and 4, I get another error:

  ```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/Users/alexwlchan/tmp/tringle.py", line 13, in <module>
      print "It's Equilateral:", xone
  NameError: name 'xone' is not defined
  ```

  The problem is that `xone` is only defined in one branch of the `if` statement, but it gets called as part of the equilateral triangle print whichever branch got followed. You need to rearrange your print statements to fix this.
- **Your check for triangles doesn't actually work.** Here's what your hint was (emphasis mine):

  > To be a triangle, the two **shortest** sides combined must be greater than the **longest** side.

  Consider my example above: 26, 13 and 4. That runs without ever warning me that it's not a triangle, but clearly such a triangle is impossible. You arbitrarily decide that `c` is the longest side, but why? There's no reason to believe that would be true.

Answer (score 2):

There are a multitude of problems here. Let's go through line by line.

```
 import math
a = input("Please Enter Side  A ")
```

This is an `IndentationError`, because the second line is dedented from the first.

```
b = input("Please Enter Side  B")
```

This isn't an error, but it is inconsistent with the other two, because it's missing a space before the `"`, so it won't look good.

```
c = input("Please Enter Side  C ")
d = a+b+c
```

This isn't an error, but it would make your code easier to debug if you called it something meaningful like, say, `perimeter`, instead of `d`.

```
if d < (2*c)
```

You're missing a `:` here. This is a syntax error. All compound statements like `if` have colons.

Also, this doesn't mean "A + B + C must be greater than twice the longest side." You're comparing A + B + C to twice the *last* side, which should just as easily be the shortest. Also, "less than" doesn't mean "not greater"; "less than or equal" means "not greater". So, what you probably want here is `if d <= 2*max(a, b, c)`.

```
     print"Shame on you, that is not a triangle!"
elif d > (2*c):
     print"You Have Two Possible Answers: "
```

This isn't an error, but… there are *three* possible answers: equilateral, isosceles, and *neither*.

Also, printing out `You Have Two Possible Answers:` and then printing `It's Equilateral: True` and then `It's Isosceles: False` is not the same thing as printing out `It is an equilateral triangle`, which is what the assignment asked for. Often class assignments—and, even more so, real-life programs—are tested by an automated test, not by a human being who can say, "Yeah, that's kind of the same thing, 90% credit." So, even if that isn't true here, you should get used to writing your output exactly as specified (and, ideally, writing your *own* test cases to check the output).

```
else:
```

This isn't (directly) an error, but… why are there three separate cases instead of just two? What's special about the case where they're equal (neither less nor greater)?

```
     xone = a=b=c
```

This is legal code, but it doesn't mean what you think. The `=` means *assignment*, so you're taking the value of `c`, and assigning it to `xone`, `a`, and `b`. What you wanted here was `==` for equality testing: `xone = a == b == c`. (And likewise for the next line.)

Also, `xone` and `xtwo` are again meaningless names; why not `is_equilateral` and `is_isosceles`?

```
     xtwo = a=b
```

This has the same problems as above, but it's also not the right test. `a == b` only tests whether the *first* two sides are equal. What if the first and third sides are equal? What you need here is something like `a==b or b==c or a==c`.

Also, as written, your code will say that an equilateral triangle is both equilateral and isosceles. I'm not sure whether that's correct under the definition you were given.

```
print "It's Equilateral:",xone,"
```

Because you've dedented this, it runs in all three cases. But you only assigned something to `xone` in the third case, so you're going to get a `NameError` unless `d == 2*c`.

Also, you have a stray `"` at the end. That will give you a syntax error, because a (non-triple-quoted) string that isn't closed by the end of the line is illegal.

```
print "It's Isosceles:",xtwo,"
```

This has the exact same two problems as the previous line.

Unless you fix *all* of these problems, your code isn't going to run and perform your logic. (And of course unless your logic is correct, it still won't be right… but you can test that once you get it running.)

Answer (score 0):

Probably your program won't produce the result you expected as it is, but this line:

```py
if d < (2*c)
```

Lacks a colon, like:

```
if d < (2*c):
```

Comment: I tried but that doesn't seem to be the reason. I get an error that says this...                                                      File "<stdin>", line 2
    a = input("Please Enter Side  A ")
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent

Comment: @python2learn: You have _multiple_ errors in your code, and you have to fix _all_ of them, not just one, before it will run.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. I hope this will work fine for you

```
a = input("Please Enter Side  A ")
b = input("Please Enter Side  B")
c = input("Please Enter Side  C ")
d = a+b+c
if d < (2*c) or d<(2*a) or d<(2*b):
     print"Shame on you, that is not a triangle!"
else:
    print "You have two possible answers"
    if(a==b==c):
        print "It's Equilateral: "
    elif(a==b)or(b==c)or(a==c):
        print "It's Isosceles: "
```

Comment: It's ok to post bits of code to show how to fix syntax or logic errors, but it's probably _not_ a Good Idea to do people's homework for them. I know it's fun to write code, but it's _much_ better to explain the problems in the question-asker's code, like alexwlchan and abarnert have done. [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) has more to say on this topic. And I suggest you look at that page too, iuysal.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should check the validity of each side of the triangle in your code as well. So something like this might work for you:

```
a = input("Please Enter Side  A ")
b = input("Please Enter Side  B")
c = input("Please Enter Side  C ")

d = a + b + c

if (d < (2*a)) or (d < (2*b)) or (d < (2*c)): # Make sure that each side is valid
    print "Shame on you, that is not a triangle!"

elif (a==b==c):
    print "It's Equilateral"

elif (a==b) or (a==c) or (b==c):
    print "It's Isosceles"
```

Answer (score 0):

Many people have already told you how to correct your code. Ill try to tell you some ways to make your life easier when programming in Python.

1. Learn about lists. Then you can handle all sides of the triangle as `sides = [a,b,c]`.
2. Note that a particular set of `sides` belongs to a triangle if (2 * *maximum* side) < (the *sum* of its sides). Learn about the commands `sum` and `max` which work on lists. How can you check for this condition uisng these functions?
3. Learn about the command `set`. This function takes a list and gives you *unique* values within the list. How many unique sides does an equilateral and isoceles triangle have? Can you use the `len` function along with the `set` function to figure out if a triangle is isosceles it equilateral?

Think about the solutions. Python is a very rich language allowing you to solve problems in very succient manner. The more you learn about the different datatypes availabel in Python, the easier it will be to solve problems.

Cheers!